# Does Sitecore content editor have native way to display a pop-up box on a page

Tags: sitecore, content-editor

I want to be able to prompt a user for their first/last and email on a page using a pop-up window.  Is there a way to do that rather than just a "flat" form or relying on Javascript?

TIA!

Not sure of the best approach to accomplish this.  Of course a form would work but would prefer a more attention getting popup.  Also want to avoid using Javascript